# Outlook VBA - Bulk Move of Email Between Subfolders

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I routinely have to move a decent amount of email (150+) from a subfolder to another. There are many folders in the mailbox that I perform this task on. It seems like it would be an easy macro to write, but what I have is substantially slower than doing a Ctrl+A, drag to destination folder.

I have reviewed previous questions about moving Outlook emails and Microsoft's documentation, but I am unable to figure out how to accomplish moving the emails in a a fast and reliable manner. I would appreciate any information on where I am going wrong and if there is another solution besides VBA.

My current code is below. My end goal would be to loop through a list of folder names (instead of me selecting the folder).

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub MoveEmailsToDone()

On Error Resume Next

Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim AnalystFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim MoveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set AnalystFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set MoveToFolder = ns.Folders("username@domain.com").Folders(AnalystFolder.Name & "-DONE")

For i = AnalystFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    AnalystFolder.Items(i).Move MoveToFolder
Next i

Set ns = Nothing
Set AnalystFolder = Nothing
Set MoveToFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From experience Move and Delete are slow.

http://computer-programming-forum.com/1-vba/17216b85e9c096d3.htm

> 07 Jul 2003
>   The following code loops through each mail item in a specified folder
>   and moves the item to another folder.  For 1100 items, it takes more
>   than 5 min.  It doesn't move that slow when I select all and move in
>   the user interface.

.

> Outlook uses Extended MAPI to implement a move operation, namely
>   IMAPIFolder::CopyMessages() which takes a list of entryids, hence it does not
>   need to open each message. Store provider completes the whole operation on the
>   server without sending lots of data back and forth as apparently happens when
>   you run your code.
>
> Dmitry Streblechenko

https://stackoverflow.com/users/332059/dmitry-streblechenko

DoEvents lets you use Outlook while the code runs.

```
For i = AnalystFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

    DoEvents    
    AnalystFolder.Items(i).Move MoveToFolder      

Next i

MsgBox "MoveEmailsToDone is finally done."
```